# Echo row values from Firebird database

Tags: php, html, echo, firebird

I'm trying to print the result of mysql query from Firebird database.
Query returns usually one row with 6 values. The code works up to here:

```
$result = ibase_query($con,$query);

function ibase_num_rows($query) { 
    $i = 0;
    while (ibase_fetch_row($query)) {
        $i++;
    }
    return $i;
}

$num_results = ibase_num_rows($result);
```

When I echo the `num_results` in html, it show right value. But when I want to echo the values from database, nothing shows up.

```
for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
    $row = ibase_fetch_object($result);

    echo "
        <div class='container'>
        <hr>
        <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-lg-7'>
    ";

    echo "
        <p><strong>".($i+1).". something: 
        $row[0]
        </strong><br /><strong>something: 
        $row[1]
        </strong><br />something: 
        $row[2]
        </strong><br/>something: 
        $row[3]
        </strong><br/>something: 
        $row[4]
        <br/>something: 
        $row[5]
        </p>
        </div>
    ";

    // ...
}
$result->free();
$con->ibase_close();
```

Does anybody know, what I'm doing wrong? I've tried many various possibilities how to print the Firebird query results but with no success.
Thanks a lot.

BTW, the query looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT STOREBATCHES.NAME, STOREBATCHES.NOTE, STORECARDS.NAME, STORECARDS.CODE, STORESUBBATCHES.QUANTITY, USERDATA.STRINGFIELDVALUE";
$query.= " FROM STOREBATCHES";
$query.= " JOIN STORECARDS";
$query.= " ON STOREBATCHES.STORECARD_ID = STORECARDS.ID";
$query.= " JOIN STORESUBBATCHES";
$query.= " ON STOREBATCHES.ID = STORESUBBATCHES.STOREBATCH_ID";
$query.= " JOIN USERDATA";
$query.= " ON STOREBATCHES.ID = USERDATA.ID";
$query.= " WHERE STOREBATCHES.NAME = '".$searchterm."' AND STORESUBBATCHES.STORE_ID = '1000000101'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = ibase_query($con,$query);

while ($row = ibase_fetch_row($res)) 
{
    foreach($row as $key => $value) 
    {
        echo $key.": ".$value;
    }
 }
```

Comment: While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = ibase_query($con,$query);
while($row = ibase_fetch_row($result))
{
  foreach($row as $key => $value)
{
  $value; (if you want particular value then write a if condition here.)
}
}
echo "
<div class='container'>
<hr>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-lg-7'>
";

     echo "
     <p><strong>'.$value.'
     </strong><br /><strong>
     </p>
     </div>
     ";

  }
```